# Writing content in an excel sheet in an incremental way

Tags: java

Hi friends i am facing one issue while writing the content in an excel sheet incrementally.When i try to add the next content in an existing excel sheet. I loose the previous one.Can any one help me to resolve this.Here is the code for this.
I have created two java classes 
1.ReadXLSheet -->to read the file 
2.Create--> to write the content incrementally.

Kindly look into it and resolve this issue.

```
package com.ExcelExample;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Locale;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.WorkbookSettings;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.Formula;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;
import jxl.DateCell;


public class ReadXLSheet {
    private WritableCellFormat times;
    public void init(String filePath) {
        FileInputStream fs = null;
        try {
            fs = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
            contentReading(fs);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fs.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // Returns the Headings used inside the excel sheet
    public void getHeadingFromXlsFile(Sheet sheet) {
        int columnCount = sheet.getColumns();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            System.out.println(sheet.getCell(i, 0).getContents());
        }
    }



    public void contentReading(InputStream fileInputStream)
            throws WriteException {
        WorkbookSettings ws = null;
        Workbook workbook = null;
        Sheet s = null;
        Cell rowData[] = null;
        int rowCount = '0';
        int columnCount = '0';
        DateCell dc = null;
        int totalSheet = 0;

        try {
            ws = new WorkbookSettings();
            ws.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
            workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(fileInputStream, ws);

            totalSheet = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
            if (totalSheet > 0) {
                System.out.println("Total Sheet Found:" + totalSheet);
                for (int j = 0; j < totalSheet; j++) {
                    System.out.println("Sheet Name:"
                            + workbook.getSheet(j).getName());
                }
            }


            s = workbook.getSheet(0);

            // Reading Individual Cell
            getHeadingFromXlsFile(s);


            System.out.println("Total Rows inside Sheet:" + s.getRows());
            rowCount = s.getRows();


            create c = new create();
            c.writeContent(rowCount);
            // Total Total No Of Columns in Sheet
            System.out.println("Total Column inside Sheet:" + s.getColumns());
            columnCount = s.getColumns();


            workbook.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ReadXLSheet xlReader = new ReadXLSheet();
            xlReader.init("c:/temp/lars.xls");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.ExcelExample;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

import jxl.CellView;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.WorkbookSettings;
import jxl.format.UnderlineStyle;
import jxl.write.Formula;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.Number;
import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat;
import jxl.write.WritableFont;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;


public class create {

    private WritableCellFormat timesBoldUnderline;
    private WritableCellFormat times;
    private String inputFile;

public void setOutputFile(String inputFile) {
    this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }

    public void write(int rowCount) throws IOException, WriteException {

        File file = new File(inputFile);
        System.out.println("Inside write 1");
        WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

        wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

        System.out.println("Inside write 2");


        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);

        System.out.println("Inside write 3");
        workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
        System.out.println("Inside write 4");

        WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
        System.out.println("Inside write 4");
        createLabel(excelSheet);

        System.out.println("Inside write 5");
        createContent(excelSheet,rowCount);
        System.out.println("Inside write 6");

        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();
    }

    private void createLabel(WritableSheet sheet)
            throws WriteException {
        // Lets create a times font
        WritableFont times10pt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 10);
        // Define the cell format
        times = new WritableCellFormat(times10pt);
        // Lets automatically wrap the cells
        times.setWrap(true);

        // Create create a bold font with unterlines
        WritableFont times10ptBoldUnderline = new WritableFont(
                WritableFont.TIMES, 10, WritableFont.BOLD, false,
                UnderlineStyle.SINGLE);
        timesBoldUnderline = new WritableCellFormat(times10ptBoldUnderline);
        // Lets automatically wrap the cells
        timesBoldUnderline.setWrap(true);

        CellView cv = new CellView();
        cv.setFormat(times);
        cv.setFormat(timesBoldUnderline);
        cv.setAutosize(true);

        // Write a few headers
        addCaption(sheet, 0, 0, "Header 1");
        addCaption(sheet, 1, 0, "This is another header");


    }

    private void createContent(WritableSheet sheet, int rowCount) throws WriteException,
            RowsExceededException {
        // Now a bit of text
        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            // First column
            addLabel(sheet, 0, i+rowCount, "Adding New text " );
            // Second column
            addLabel(sheet, 1, i+rowCount, "New Text text");
        }
    }

    private void addCaption(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s)
            throws RowsExceededException, WriteException {
        Label label;
        label = new Label(column, row, s, timesBoldUnderline);
        sheet.addCell(label);
    }

    private void addNumber(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row,
            Integer integer) throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
        Number number;
        number = new Number(column, row, integer, times);
        sheet.addCell(number);
    }

    private void addLabel(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, String s)
            throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
        Label label;
        label = new Label(column, row, s, times);
        sheet.addCell(label);
    }


    public void writeContent(int rowCount)  throws WriteException, IOException {
        create test = new create();
        test.setOutputFile("c:/temp/lars.xls");
        test.write(rowCount);
        System.out
                .println("Please check the result file under c:/temp/lars.xls ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your are creating a blank workbook instead of modifying the existing one. Instead of using Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings), use Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wb), where wb is the workbook that you previously read.